Laravel form not sending IDs
ID input
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" value="{{ Auth()->user()->id }}">

After dump
"_token" => "BP0ejzEjoIjFyUonjdMFNAyoRDcYCr4k7nec5czI"
"name" => "Mark"
"surname" => "Johanessburg"
"number" => "8281992832"
"email" => "mark@yahoo.com"

So I'm trying to send the user's ID through the form. But when I clicked the submit button and do a dd, there is no ID sent. What can I do to fix this or is there something I did wrong? Thank you in advance.

It can be hard to find the right search terms, but if you try for eg "php form input missing" you will find plenty of others who have asked and answerd this problem before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304445/missing-fields-when-submitting-form, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885318/post-variable-is-missing, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268785/missing-data-on-form-submit-php-application, ...

Does this answer your question? Missing fields when submitting form

The name attribute was missing on the input element:
<input class="form-control" name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ Auth()->user()->id }}">


U need to add name attribute to the input field to get it in the submitted data
<input class="form-control" name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ Auth()->user()->id }}">

The name attribute is used by the request object to get the form field data...
